# Best CMS / Wiki whatever for a Code Samples Website

Tags: asp.net, web, content-management-system, wiki, sample

I need a CMS / Wiki whatever to present our code samples.

We use NopCommerce in the frontend of our website ([www.crawler-lib.net](http://www.crawler-lib.net/)) which has nearly no support for that. The library documentation is done with Sandcastle and SHFB wich we put on a differnet host ([help.crawler-lib.net](http://help.crawler-lib.net/)). We could use conceptual content for our code samples, but this is a big waste of time. I have tried Document! X and it is not even better. So I think of setting up a codes sample site on a different host (samples.crawler-lib.net). Features like syntax highlighting and videos (We do a lot of videos at YouTube: [Crawler-Lib YouTube Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/CrawlerLib)) are mandatory. Have you any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally decided to put the code samples on the NopCommerce website. Using the [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) this will be better than a different host with a CMS because it keeps all together.